# Common fraction for :$\frac{1}{x^2-2x+2}+\frac{2}{ x^2-2x+3}=\frac{6}{ x^2-2x+4}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, fractions

Hi guys please help me with this equation:
$$\frac{1}{x^2-2x+2}+\frac{2}{ x^2-2x+3}=\frac{6}{ x^2-2x+4}$$
My problem is with finding common fraction for denominators ($x^2-2x+2$ and  $x^2-2x+3$and $x^2-2x+4$).
I actually want to find a common fraction , then cross It for hole equation and to simplify it. Then solve for x.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\frac{1}{(x-1)^2+1}+\frac{2}{ (x-1)^2+2}=\frac{6}{ (x-1)^2+3}$$

and by $y=(x-1)^2$

$$\frac{1}{y+1}+\frac{2}{ y+2}=\frac{6}{ y+3} \iff(y+2)(y+3)+2(y+1)(y+3)=6(y+1)(y+2)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot gimusi you helped me solving the puzzle!

Comment: @user602338 Well done! Solve for y and then for x.

Comment: Just i didnt realize something.what did you do at last section?

Comment: Would you explain a bit more? @gimusi

Comment: @user602338 Multiplying the whole equation with $(y+1)(y+2)(y+3)$ after setting $y=(x-1)^2$.

Comment: @user602338 Carry out the calculation from the last one and you'll find an equation for $y$. Once you find the solution(s) for $y_0$ we can set $(x-1)^2=y_0$ and find $x$.

Comment: @user602338 Let proceed one step at time, can you find $y$?

Comment: Sure @gimusi I can solve the hole puzzle.

Comment: @user602338 That's fine! If you show your work in the OP I'll take a look to it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84706/discussion-between-user602338-and-gimusi).